# angular directive causes rest of template not to get rendered - what are the possible reasons that this could happen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

When I add my custom directive to a template for one of my existing pages, which previously rendered correctly, only this directive renders, and the rest of the template does not.

Examining console logs as well as Batarang shows that the controller has been executed. An inspection of the rendered DOM, however, shows that none of the remainder of the template has been rendered.

Interestingly, when I insert this directive at the bottom of the template, instead of right at the top, as I had been doing prior, the original template does indeed get rendered once more, and the `navTabs` directive at the bottom.

- What are the possible reasons this could happen?
- Is there anything in particular that I can investigate or prod?

---

Full details:

I add `<nav-tabs />` to an existing template.

The directive, `navTabs.js`

```
   /* In charge of the navigation within the app */
    'use strict';    
    var App = angular.module('app');
    App.directive('navTabs', function() {
        var tabs = [
            {id:'x', title: 'Xx', url: '/x'},
            {id:'y', title: 'Yy', url: '/y'}
        ];
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'views/navTabs.html',
            // scope: {},
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.tabs = tabs;
            }
        };
    });
```

The template, `views/navTabs.html`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
        <a href="#{{tab.url}}">{{tab.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Update (20140220):

Interestingly, I have found that using the directive as so:

```
<nav-tabs />
```

... causes this strange behaviour, whereas, using this form:

```
<nav-tabs></nav-tabs>
```

Behaves as expected, when placed at the top of the template. When placed at the bottom of the template, it does not matter which form is used.

---

Update  (20140220):

Raised an issue against angular on github, see their response: [github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6360](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6360)

Comment: Interesting. Can you give more details of the template into which the directive is placed - for example, is it itself a template of another directive? Where in the template is this directive placed? Inside another directive perhaps? Can you post the original template which contains the directive?

Comment: @callmekatootie (1) Nope, the other template is simply the template for a controller, directly invoked by the router. (2 & 3) This directive, when placed at the top of the template, causes this problem, when placed at the bottom, does not. (4) Unfortunately, that template is pretty big. I'll try to put together a SSCCE for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When including your own directive, using a "void tag" is not possible, as explained in [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6360).

- Good: `<my-directive></my-directive>`
- Bad: `<my-directive />`

HTH anyone else who gets snagged with this strange behaviour.

Comment: Worth adding that angular will not provide an error message in this case in some (most) cases.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var App = angular.module('app');
```

to

```
var App = angular.module('app',[]);
```

Comment: I have previously declared App, and am merely referencing it here. doing that would declare a new App, and cause a lot more problems than the one I mention here!